# copy current HTML page state to MySQL table so users can access later the saved file

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Ok so my problem here is that I have created a page with a table. this table can be cloned infinite times and data is inserted or manually, or from data fetched from a sql table. This means each table created is different.

The point of this page is for users to create their own personal tables, and then be able to save the current page on a specific sql table so they can head back to it whenever they like and therefor load it back to its saved state.

This means each user will have used the same table, but each users tables will have different values in it!

I have very little knowledge in php and have just recently started to use jquery. My question is how can I work out a way to copy the current html page state, and save it to a specific sql table?

This php grabs everything inside `<html>` and `</html>`.

```
<?PHP
    echo "<button class=\"Button\" onclick=\"console.log(getPageHTML());\">Print all html</button>";
    ?>
```

so far so good. How can i now save this to a sql table? Php will be needed but how?

Hope all this was clear enough.
Help would be great on this one. Thanks

Comment: Since your using jQuery and the HTML is on client side, you need to use Javascript to store the WebPage. the HTML won't exist within the scope of PHP unless the page is posted to a PHP script

Answer (score 4):

The `getPageHTML()` is executed on the client's side, so you have to upload it to the server again, where you will have to save the state into your database.

Things you need:

- a structure to save the table in the database
- knowledge of GET (POST would be better) or AJAX (best) requests
- minimal SQL knowledge

You could also save the data to a static file on the server (but don't forget to prevent them from overriding someone elses table).

My idea:

1. button uploads only table to server
2. server checks for content size (eg. <=1KB)
3. server creates hash (best would be SHA512)
4. server saves the file to .html (with a header and footer to surround the table)
5. send the user the link to the site

links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http#Request_methods
- http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json

**That** project could take a while to realize `;)`

EDIT:

You could give the table an id (`<table id="someusefulid">…</table>`) and then use JavaScripts `document.getElementById()` to retrieve its HTML.

Have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/) site. It has plenty of examples. First of all look at the basics of JavaScript's DOM to be able to access the table, then try to upload it somehow (preferably AJAX, which is a bit more to study) and after that you can get to the PHP code.

But do always remember, if you read or write files using PHP, be extremely cautious.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. if i understood then, the idea of getPageHTML() is not such a bad idea, maybe just not tacking the whole page. getting just the body elements for example. this would mean nos saving scripts and so on. and then having a sort of template with all the scripts in it and inserting the body into it? will take a look at those 3 links. will need to learn a load more of php it seems :-). Cheers

Comment: yes but as said, I am cloning this table and giving it new Id's each time. so table_01 cloned becomes table_02 and so on...  My page ends up with multiple tables created after the original. Thank you for your help. Maybe should i try already to simply copy a html file to a sql table to start off. once I manage this, I will be able to complicate things ;)